# Conversion error when using Python 2to3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2to3

When running this cmd:

```
2to3  util.py -v -p -w
```

I have this message :

```
RefactoringTool: Adding transformation: zip
RefactoringTool: Can't parse util.py: ParseError: bad input: type=1, value='f', context=(' ', (150, 11))
RefactoringTool: No changes in util.py
RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.
RefactoringTool: There was 1 error:
RefactoringTool: Can't parse util.py: ParseError: bad input: type=1, value='f', context=(' ', (150, 11))
```

1) How to identify the line of the file concerned ?

Comment: `(150, 11)` ---> line number, column?

Comment: maybe..., after checking this line, columns nothing strange... (it  is comments). Any doc referencing the output of 2to3